# VHDL: Comparing a big vector to value and assigning values

Tags: vhdl

I want to compare a vector of 32 bits. e.g.

bit_vector: in std_logic_vector(0 to 31);
...
if ( bit_vector /= zero) then .... -- Here I want to check whether it is zero or not.

What will write instead of that "**zero**"? any compact format?

I think we will write **if ( bit_vector /= x'0')** ? -- not sure

Please explain that how to check here? and if I want to assign some initial value to any other signal then what will be the method. e.g

signal some_signal : std_logic_vector(0 to 31) := ??? --- I want to know options other than like the ones  "**00000000110000010101010100000000**".

Thanks and cheers

Tahir

Answer (score 4):

First part of your question can be written like this:

```
if bit_vector /= (bit_vector'range=>'0') then
```

Some examples for the second part:

```
...
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...

signal some_signal : std_logic_vector(0 to 31) := x"00000000";
signal some_signal : std_logic_vector(0 to 31) := "00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000";
signal some_signal : std_logic_vector(0 to 31) := (3=>'1', 17=>'1', others=>'0');
signal some_signal : std_logic_vector(0 to 31) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(123456789, 32));
```

Comment: What if I want to equate value in decimal numbers?

Comment: @tahirsengine Use IEEE package numeric_std for that case. I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you. Actually I wanted to test a value that is in decimal. e.g see the statement   if a_variable = 8d"5" then .... Now when I am entering data, ide is complaining that this is only available in the VHDL 2008. So, we are workarounds in this situation?

Comment: @tahirsengine Either switch your IDE to VHDL-2008 or try something like to_unsigned(5, 8).

Comment: @ Juergen thanks buddy. I switched that on through Vivado IDE. Now its working.

Comment: With VHDL-2008 you can also write `:= 32d"123456789";` it takes 123456789 as **d**ecimal value and expands to 32 bit. Other modifiers are **b**inary, **o**ctal and he**x**adecimal. You should use vectors in `downto` direction.